# Error starting JBoss 7.1.1 on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: java, jboss

I'm learning to use Jboss so I tried to install it.
I downloaded it and dezip into C:.
I have created Environment variable and is all ok.

when I launch standalone.bat I have this java exception:
what I must to do to fix it?

```
16:14:04,199 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
16:14:04,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
16:14:04,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
16:14:04,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
16:14:04,226 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
16:14:04,222 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
16:14:04,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:14:04,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
16:14:04,332 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
16:14:04,337 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
16:14:04,373 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
16:14:04,446 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
16:14:04,665 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
16:14:04,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
16:14:04,727 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
16:14:04,767 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-12) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9999
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:109) [jboss-as-remoting-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpServer(NioXnioWorker.java:287)
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamServer(XnioWorker.java:135) [xnio-api-3.0.3.GA.jar:3.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider$ProviderInterface.createServer(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:209) [jboss-remoting-3.2.3.GA.jar:3.2.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.remoting.AbstractStreamServerService.start(AbstractStreamServerService.java:101) [jboss-as-remoting-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more

16:14:04,902 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:14:04,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use: bind /127.0.0.1:9999

16:14:04,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:14:04,925 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 1967ms - Started 132 of 208 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`

Comment: Do you already have an instance of it running in the background that you've forgotten about, or something else using that port?

Answer (score 20):

The port is being used by NVidia on my system. So the service can be stopped as detailed here
http://azureel.blogspot.fi/2014/01/nvidia-network-service-and-jboss-for.html

Answer (score 11):

go to standalone.xml change the port 9999 assigned for management to something else. this is also applicable when you get this exception from running jboss inside eclipse.

Comment: We had an internal web service running on 9999 which collided with JBOSS Remoting Management. This answer is very helpful from configuration stand point.

Comment: @arunram - your solution has worked for me as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

1) Make sure you have Maven installed by typing "mvn --version" in the command prompt.

2) Go to command prompt and type in "netstat". If you're like me and have a service using that port, then you might see this:

[image]

Make sure your computer doesn't have NVIDIA Network Service (NvNetworkService.exe) running as a Service. To check this, Control+Alt+Delete and go to Task Manager. Then under the Services tab, look for NvNetworkService:

[image]

[image]
After you have stopped the service, you can check if the port is freed up by going to command prompt and typing "netstat" again. This time, you should not see any foreign address associated with you 127.0.0.1:990 local address. Or if you're like me, you might see this:

[image]

Here is another similar example= https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/WildFly8xjavanetBindExceptionAddressAlreadyInUseOnFreshInstallInWindowsVista78

Answer (score 1):

in Linux mint, I've run this command 
netstat -npl 
to find ouu PID for 127.0.0.1:9990 and then I've run 
sudo kill -TERM  and I resolved!

Answer (score 0):

go to task manager and kill all the java processes and then try to run again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So as it is message saying `jboss` binding address already use by another process. So kill that process first.

You can find out process by following bellow steps

To match the process ID to a program

```
Press CTRL+ALT+DELETE, and then click Task Manager.
Click the Processes tab.
If you do not have a PID column, click View, click Select Columns, and then click to select the PID (Process Identifier) check box.
Click the column header that is labeled "PID" to sort the process by their PIDs. You should be able to easily find the process ID and match it to the program that is listed in Task Manager.
```

To obtain additional information about the Netstat.exe utility

```
Click Start, and then click Run.
In the Open box, type: cmd, and then click OK.
At a command prompt, type: netstat /?.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

standalone.bat

is using

standalone.conf.bat

Open in notepad

Add the last 2 lines (as seen below, aka the 2 "Alter Port Settings Offset" lines) (where the first 3 lines below provide the breadcrumb to where to place it)

```
rem # Make Byteman classes visible in all module loaders
rem # This is necessary to inject Byteman rules into AS7 deployments
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"

REM NEW LINE HERE Alter Port Settings Offset
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look for http://<>:9999/console to check if the JBoss Management console is running in your instance. If so please kill the server and redeploy. In most scenarios like mine while configuring the JBoss servers in IDE's such as IntelliJ, the shutdown script might not be called out explicitly, because of which the JBoss console that is launched in the beginning would have never been brought down, which might stand in out way. Hope this helps.